# Push notification in Windows Phone limit

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, push-notification

I have sent push notifications for Windows Phony without certificate. I know there is limit 500 pushes per day.
My question is: 500 pushes is limit per day and per phone or per day and sending application?
For example: I have four mobiles. How many pushes can I max send by my app a day without buy certificate?

Answer (score 2):

The limit is by subscription and day. By subscription mean by channel URI. So your service can send a max of 500 notifications by device/user, you can take a look at this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941099%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [here](http://blog.mjfnet.com/2012/03/19/windows-phone-push-notifications-frequently-asked-questions/).

Answer (score 1):

By default, the limit is 500 notifications per channel URI per day. So if you have multiple notifications (say Toast and Tile) in your application, you can send 500 of each type. That is 500 of each type of notification per device / user. For example, if you have 100 users of your application and 1 type of notification, you can send up to 50,000 `(1 * 500 * 100)` notifications per day. Authenticated notifications are unlimited.